# Prove all ines of the form all lines of the form $(a+2)x - (a+1)y - 2a - 3 = 0$ pass through a common point

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

What is the easiest proof to prove that all lines of the form  $(a+2)x - (a+1)y - 2a - 3 = 0$ pass through some common point, where $a$ is a real number, and how to find that point. I tried taking $a_1$ and $a_2$ and somehow to prove it with determinants, but I got stuck.

Comment: It is quite trivial that if we take $x=1$ and $y=-1$...

Comment: Solution is obvious, yes, but how can I get to that solution?

Comment: For which values of $x,y$ the LHS does not depend on $a$?

Comment: the part containing $a$ is : $a(x-y-2)$. So, $x-y-2=0$ must hold. Furthermore, $2x-y-3=0$ must hold. This gives the unique solution.

Comment: Among such values, which $(x,y)$ couples lead to an LHS equal to zero?

Answer (score 2):

Rearranging and factoring yields:

$a(x-y-2)+(2x-y-3)=0$

Here are the two possibilities:

1. There is a point on this line such that the equation cancels out.
2. There is a point where the coefficient of $a$ turns out to be $0$

The first case isn't all too interesting. In order for that to happen you would have to stick $a$ in place, which would lead to a line of solutions and that's boring.

Here's the best part. If we can guarantee that the coefficient of $a$ becomes $0$ and the other constant equals $0$ then $a$ can be anything. More generally it can lead to as many lines as you wish passing through a singular point.

What singular point? The one that satisfies the necessary equations:

$x-y-2=0 \tag 1$

$2x-y-3=0 \tag 2$

You can use $(1)$ to create a displacement:

$(x-y-2)+x-1=0 \implies x-1=0$

I rest my case.

Answer (score 1):

I would choose values for $a$ that eliminate one variable.  If $a=-2$ you get an equation in $y$ only. If $a=-1$, you get an equation in $x$ only.  The solutions to these two equations are the coordinates you want.

Comment: Another way, perhaps even more elegant.